# Google AppMaker: data import not working from sheet

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to import to an AppMaker app and all I can get is the following error:

```
JDBC backend failure. More information: 
Error while executing SQL statement: 
Incorrect string value: '\xC2\xA0' for column 
'business_name' at row 1. 0 records imported
```

I know this has something to do with UTF-8 or character sets, but I have no clue how to solve it!
The spreadsheet is dead simple address info columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to recreate the Cloud SQL database and specifically choose type as:

> utf8mb4

Cloud SQL defaults to utf8.  I could then import the data.